# Extract Only Specific Files with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have to extract only "daily" files from a folder in my C: drive into azure data factory but there are "weekly" files that I don't want to extract. Also, I can't separate the two files in different onprem folders. I have to do this for a client but first I'm practicing on my own computer. [Here is the onprem folder that I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9ljg.png). So the ultimate goal is to only transfer the "daily" files out of the folder and into azure data factory

Comment: [tag:azure-pipelines] is for a specific offering that is **not** related to data factory. Please review tag summaries to ensure you're applying appropriate tags to your questions.

Comment: use a wildcard (daily*) since the naming convention tells you what type of file it is.

Comment: you can also use get metadata activity to get files name and the filer the file names by using filter activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by **@Scott Mildenberger** in comments as your files have similar naming convention you can use `wildcard file path` to filter files with name.

- **Sample data**

[image]

- **Dataset settings**

[image]

- **Source Setting**

In file path type select `wildcard file path`  and give **daily*** It will filter all the files from folder with files contains **daily**.

[image]

- **Output**

[image]